# Terminology used to distinguish between different types of answers

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, semantics

Does a scientific classification exist for distinguishing between different types of answers?  For example, one answer might be complete, leaving no further questions; a second could provide only a partial answer; a third may provide an answer which has no relevance to the question; then a fourth may answer the question completely or partially, but lead to additional questions.  I am seeking terminology with precise definitions instead of the plethora of adjectives I could utilize that would be open to interpretation.

Comment: You just provided as much as probably exists.  The problem with such classification is that it assumes other information; never forget the unknown unknowns.

Comment: What you're asking for is A Taxonomy of Answers.  In an alternative universe, Aristotle may have provided one. :-)

Comment: Surely any partial answer leaves additional questions (if only 'What is a better answer?')

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -  Or “Where’s the rest of it?”

Comment: The word "definitive" comes to mind... as does "alternatives" and "expansive" .  This questions does not have a definitive answer nor does it have clear alternative answers, so perhaps it would require a more expansive answer delving into the field of rhetoric and the nature of questions themselves?

Comment: I think it's fascinating to see what others have to say, but I think this is a question about epistemology and not the English language, and I'm going to vote to close.